# HLA typing between siblings to identify a genetic disorder

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, human-genetics, pathology

If a patient  suffering from a complex array of signs and symptoms for a disease and is having an 8/8 loci match with his sister who suffers no such symptoms can you conclude that the disease is an X-linked recessive disorder? Can u rule out autosomal dominant disorders and autosomal recessive disorders from the diagnosis?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't conclude that.

First of all, two siblings being HLA identical tells you very little about the rest of their genome. [HLA genes are closely linked](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2628004/), and each haplotype is transmitted in mendelian fashion as a single gene.  For non-linked genes (on other chromosomes, or further away on chromosome 6), they are as or nearly as likely to have the same genes as non-HLA identical siblings.

Further, the disease of interest may (is highly likely to) be multigenic and have incomplete penetrance. The heritability of common disorders generally varies from 20-80% (Cecil Medicine Chapter 41, the Inherited Basis of Common disorders).

Comment: Technically, there is a small chance of recombination within the HLA (MHC) region, so haplotypes are transmitted in a mostly-medelian fashion.